# Add color column to geom_bar plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I would need help in order to add scare colors into a geom_bar plot from a ggplot2 figure.

Here is what I can manage to do so far :

```
    head(data)
  x  y group Axis_color
1 A 25     F         G1
2 A 88     G         G1
3 A 88     H         G1
4 A 22     I         G1
5 A 18     J         G1
6 B 54     F         G3

color_list<- c("F"="orange", "G"="darkgreen", "H"="grey", "I"="pink", "J"="purple", "G1"="blue","G2"="red","G3"="green")
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = group, label = y)) + 
  coord_flip()+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Which gives:

[image]

But I would like to add the column "Axis_color" in order to add colors stored in the `color_list` such as :

[image]

As you can see I get two different legends axis as well.

Here are the data if it can helps :

```
structure(list(x = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E"), y = c(25, 88, 88, 22, 18, 54, 25, 37, 68, 
72, 36, 84, 17, 64, 48, 15, 17, 72, 61, 25, 66, 10, 18, 99, 63
), group = c("F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", 
"F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "F", "G", "H", 
"I", "J"), Axis_color = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G3", 
"G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", 
"G2", "G2", "G2", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3")), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to make use of `geom_tile` and the `ggnewscale` package like so.

1. For the `geom_tile` I make use of a simplified dataset containing only the unique or distinct categories and axis color values. Depending on your desired result you could adjust the width of the tiles via the `width` argument.
2. As `geom_tile` by default will result in a slightly different look of the legend keys I make use of the `override.aes` argument of `guide_legend` so that the legend keys are the same as for the `geom_col`

Note that I switched to `geom_col` and switched the role of the `x` and `y` aesthetics which allows to get rid of the `coord_flip`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

color_list<- c("F"="orange", "G"="darkgreen", "H"="grey", "I"="pink", "J"="purple", "G1"="blue","G2"="red","G3"="green")
ggplot(data, aes(x = y, y = x, fill = group, label = y)) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(.025, 0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_list[unique(data$group)], guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_tile(data = dplyr::distinct(data, x, Axis_color), aes(x = -15, y = x, fill = Axis_color), 
            height = .9, width = 15, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_list[sort(unique(data$Axis_color))], 
                    guide = guide_legend(order = 2, override.aes = list(lwd = .5, color = NA)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(ggnewscale)
library(tidyverse)

data <- structure(list(x = c(
  "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B",
  "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E",
  "E", "E", "E", "E"
), y = c(
  25, 88, 88, 22, 18, 54, 25, 37, 68,
  72, 36, 84, 17, 64, 48, 15, 17, 72, 61, 25, 66, 10, 18, 99, 63
), group = c(
  "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
  "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "F", "G", "H",
  "I", "J"
), Axis_color = c(
  "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G3",
  "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2",
  "G2", "G2", "G2", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3"
)), row.names = c(
  NA,
  -25L
), class = "data.frame")

color_list <- c("F" = "orange", "G" = "darkgreen", "H" = "grey", "I" = "pink", "J" = "purple", "G1" = "blue", "G2" = "red", "G3" = "green")


data %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = group), stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = color_list[names(color_list) %>% discard(~ .x %>% str_starts("G[0-9]"))]
  ) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Axis_color, y = -10), stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = color_list[names(color_list) %>% keep(~ .x %>% str_starts("G[0-9]"))]
  ) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>